# How to press a button on a form by pressing a button on another form in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I guess it is a simple question but I researched here for other relevant topics that didn't work for me so here it is.
By pressing the specific button in Form2, Form1 appears, and then by pressing the button in Form1 the button in Form2 has to be pressed and show a message.I don't want to use a module with global variable because I have done it this way. Is there a way to get the specific instance of Form1 and not a new one? The 2 classes are in different .vb files, here is the code:

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form2Btn1.Click
    MsgBox("")
End Sub

Private Sub form2Btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form2Btn2.Click
    Dim newForm1 As New Form1
    newForm1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
End Class
```

And the code for form1:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub form1Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    form1Btn.Click
    Dim newForm2 As New Form2
    newForm2.form2Btn1.PerformClick()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The `Form2` object in the click event is not the same form2 as what showed the dialog - you need to pass it (`Me`) to the dialog, perhaps in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes that was my problem, how to take the same instance of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposing form's controls or their event handlers to other classes not very good practice. But you can make public method which do same staff and then call it from other form.
Main idea in your solution is to pass existed/correct instance of `Form2` to the `Form1` as were suggested by @Plutonix in the comments.

So first extract logic from button_click eventhandler in `Form1` to the public method.

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Sub ShowMessage()
        MsgBox("")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form2Btn1.Click
        ShowMessage() ' call the method here
    End Sub

    Private Sub form2Btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form2Btn2.Click
        'Form implements IDisposable interface so
        'it is good practice to wrap that instance with Using statement
        Using newForm1 As New Form1(Me)
            newForm1.ShowDialog()
        End using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create constructor in `Form1` which takes this instance as parameter

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly _Form1Instance As Form1

    Public Sub New(form1Instance As Form1)
        _Form1Instance = form1instance;
    End Sub

    Private Sub form1Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    form1Btn.Click
        'Use instance of Form2 passed through constructor for calling public method
        _Form1Instance.ShowMessage()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, i will do something like that, i think that it is the best practice

Answer (score 0):

Strip off the private in Form1 Subs, ie

```
Public Class Form2
Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form2Btn1.Click
    MsgBox("")
End Sub

Sub form2Btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form2Btn2.Click
    Dim newForm1 As New Form1
    newForm1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
End Class
```

So that on Form1 you can do something like

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub form1Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    form1Btn.Click
    Dim newForm2 As New Form2
    newForm2.Button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but i really don't want to change the buttons private status